# jquery menubar - jquery,javascript,css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I want to display icon in place of menu name on menubar.

Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Bvap/.
For the main menu items (i.e.,Item1,Item2,Item3..) i want to show image and upon user click on that image i want to show submenu items name as shown for Item3 menu item in fiddle.

Below is the sample code i used to create menu bar using jquery.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-13</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest how to show icon in place of menu names. Thanks.

--EDIT--

Below are the imports i'm using in my local application.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Please find the image below which shows menubar vertically.
[image]

Comment: you want an image icon before every lists?

Comment: no in place of main menu item name i.e., Item1,Item2,Item3.. i want to show an icon. @rickjancawaling

Comment: ahhh like background of menu items?

Comment: yes...and no need to show the menu item name.

Comment: do you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bvap/1271/)?

Comment: yes..but when i copy pasted the code in my application, menu items are shown vertically. I want them to display horizontally as shown in fiddle. Please suggest what modification to be done in my file to show menubar horizontally. Thanks,@rickjancawaling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78439/discussion-between-rick-jan-cawaling-and-user222).

Comment: sorry, its showing website blocked @rickjancawaling

Comment: it's working fine for me. what are browser are u using for your project?

Comment: in jsfiddle its fine, but when i copied and pasted the same in my local application which run on tomcat server, its showing vertical menubar as shown in the picture posted above..@rickjancawaling

Comment: yay just add in your css ul li  { float: left; } 
im going to post my answer like at the top if it's correct

Comment: sorry for the trouble but please see the image attached in post above when used ul li { float: left; }.  Appreciate your help.. @rickjancawaling

Comment: haha it's fine i've been there. put your codes into fiddle and i will edit it and post it as answer here.

Comment: Thanks. Please find the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vpn9c163/ . I have kept the imports too which i'm using in my application. However in jsfiddle with the same code its showing horizontally but in my application it is same as the image i posted above. And in fiddle for 3rd menu item when i click its not showing the submenu items.@rickjancawaling

Comment: ok im making a fiddle. i'll post it here later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bvap/1274/)

Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVdaWXKz6j8) for the tutorial it will help you to make navigation bar using pure css.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/red-tab/32/Apple-Menu-items-icon.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "#nav" ).menu({position: {at: "left bottom"}});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-menu { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.ui-menu > li { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: auto !important;
}
.ui-menu ul li {
    display:block;
    float:none;
    background-image: url ();
}
.ui-menu ul li ul {
    left:120px !important;
    width:100%;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul li {
    width:auto;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul li a {
    float:left;
}
.ui-menu > li {
    margin: 5px 5px !important;
    padding: 0 0 !important;
}
.ui-menu > li > a { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon { 
    margin-top: 0.3em !important;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu .ui-menu li { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @rick jan cawaling..but when i copied and pasted the code in my local application its still showing vertical menubar only as shown in above posted image. may be the imports is making the trouble. But ur answer is correct. Appreciate your help and effort. But no luck , i will investigate more to find out the exact problem when ran in local application using tomcat server...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have checked out the jQuery Menu widget: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/

The menu uses icons, however it's in addition to the text.

I think your best bet would be to check this out - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/23/css-tutorial-image-with-toolbar-navigation-overlay/

The tutorial seems to cover everything you need.